# Matlab - rotate a card

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rotation, geometry, rectangles

I have a cropped image of a card:

[image: card]

The card is a rectangle with rounded corners, is brightly colored, and sits on a relatively dark background.
It is, therefore, easy to differentiate between pixels belonging to the card and pixels belonging to the background.

I want to use MATLAB to rotate the card so its sides are vertical and horizontal (and not diagonal) and create an image of nothing but the straightened card.

[image: card]

I need this to work for any reasonable card angle (say +45 to -45 degrees of initial card rotation).

What would be the best way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: The best way of doing this would be to actually code something, instead of dumping your problem here in the hope someone comes along and codes it for you.

Comment: The answers in [How to straighten a tilted square shape in an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506759/how-to-straighten-a-tilted-square-shape-in-an-image) would not work for that image, because the corners of the card are rounded.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by finding the lines made by the edges of the card. The angle of rotation is then the angle between one of the lines and the horizontal (or vertical).

In MATLAB, you can use the Hough line detector to find lines in a binary image.

**0. Read the input image**

I downloaded your image and renamed it card.png.

```
A = imread('card.png');
```

We don't need color information, so convert to grayscale.

```
I = rgb2gray(A);
```

**1. Detect edges in the image**

A simple way is to use the [Canny edge detector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html). Adjust the threshold to reject noise and weak edges.

```
BW = edge(I, 'canny', 0.5);
```

Display the detected edges.

```
figure
imshow(BW)
title('Canny edges')
```

[image: Canny edges]

**2. Use the Hough line detector**

First, you need to use the Hough transform on the black and white image, with the [`hough`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOK1n.png) function. Adjust the resolution so that you detect all lines you need later.

```
[H,T,R] = hough(BW, 'RhoResolution', 2);
```

Second, find the strongest lines in the image by finding peaks in the Hough transform with [`houghpeaks`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOK1n.png).

```
P = houghpeaks(H, 100); % detect a maximum of 100 lines
```

Third, detect lines with [`houghlines`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOK1n.png).

```
lines = houghlines(BW, T, R, P);
```

Display the detected lines to make sure you find at least one along the edge of the card. The white border around the black background in your image makes detecting the right edges a bit more difficult.

```
figure
imshow(A)
hold on
for k = 1:length(lines)
  xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
  plot(xy(:,1), xy(:,2), 'LineWidth', 2, 'Color', 'red');
end
title('Detected lines')
```

[image: Detected lines]

**3. Calculate the angle of rotation**

`lines(3)` is the left vertical edge of the card. `lines(3).point2` is the end of the line that is at the bottom. We want this point to stay where it is, but we want to vector along the line to be aligned with the vector `v = [0 -1]'`. (The origin is the top-left corner of the image, `x` is horizontal to the right and `y` is vertical down.)

```
lines(3)

ans = 

  struct with fields:

    point1: [179 50]
    point2: [86 455]
     theta: 13
       rho: 184
```

Simply calculate the angle between the vector `u = lines(3).point1 - lines(3).point2` and the vertical vector `v`.

```
u = lines(3).point1 - lines(3).point2; % vector along the vertical left edge.
v = [0 -1]; % vector along the vertical, oriented up.
theta = acos( u*v' / (norm(u) * norm(v)) );
```

The angle is in radians.

**4. Rotate**

The [`imrotate`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abf45.png) function lets you rotate an image by specifying an angle in degrees. You could also use [`imwarp`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abf45.png) with a rotation transform.

```
B = imrotate(A, theta * 180 / pi);
```

Display the rotated image.

```
figure
imshow(B)
title('Rotated image')
```

[image: Rotated image]

Then you would have to crop it.

Comment: is there any way to order the hough lines?